# Giving a SSH user permission under /media/user/data

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp

Say I have two users right now:

- mkcoldwolf
- pvpzxalan

They both have a /home/%user dir

and the user mkcoldwolf has mounted a HardDrive at /media/mkcoldwolf/Data
i want to let user pvpzxalan able to access the folder /media/mkcoldwolf/Data/folder.
Also i dont want to let user pvpzxalan access /media/mkcoldwolf/Data/other

How do I do that? I have tried linking, mount

```
sudo mount --bind --verbose /home/pvpzxalan /media/mkcoldwolf/Data/folder
```

All of them said "permission denied" or won't create the folder, what should i do?

Comment: How about creating a group like "team" and putting both users into that group? Then give group rwx permissions to /media/mkcoldwolf/Data/ for the group "team"?  And then make the group of /media/mkcoldwolf/Data/other be the default group of mkcoldwolf.  Would that work?  Perhaps play with this a bit on normal directories first, and then bring the mounting issue in after...